# codeigniter active records group_by returns random ordering of joined table record id

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I'm using Codeigniter, what I want to do is a query that returns joined table (item_gallery) gallery_id is lowest value. while main query ordered by desc of items post_date

the below code group_by select random value of item_gallery gallery_id. but i want the lowest value of item_gallery gallery_id.

```
  public function shopItems($id) {

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->join('item_gallery', 'items.id = item_gallery.item_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('items.user_id', $id);     
    $this->db->order_by('items.post_date', 'Desc');
    $this->db->group_by("item_gallery.item_id");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

database Structure

items table

```
|    id    |  slug  |  user_id  |  post_date |

|    12    |  test  |    111    |  12/5/2017 |
```

items Gallery

```
| gallery_id |  item_id  |     image     | 

|     121    |    12     |  profile.png  |   -- i want this record selected
|     122    |    12     |  gallery.png  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function shopItems($id, $limit, $start) {

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');
$expire = date('Y-m-d');
$this->db->select("*,(SELECT image FROM item_gallery WHERE item_id = 
items.id ORDER BY gallery_id ASC LIMIT 1) AS profile_img");
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->join('item_gallery', 'items.id = item_gallery.item_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('items.exp_date >', $expire);
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->where("items.status = 'yes'");
$this->db->or_where("items.status = 'edit'");
$this->db->group_end();
$this->db->where('items.user_id', $id);
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
$this->db->order_by('items.post_date', 'Desc');
$this->db->group_by("item_gallery.item_id");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$this->db->order_by('items.post_date', 'Desc');
```

With

```
 $this->db->order_by('items.id', 'Desc');
```

Comment: i want "item_gallery.id" lowest value while items.post_date desc

Comment: Then replace  `items.post_date` with  `item_gallery.id`

Comment: $this->db->group_by("item_gallery.item_id"); should select lower value of joined table, item_gallery.id. while $this->db->order_by('items.post_date', 'Desc');

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/SCB73 - item_gallery table
http://imgur.com/a/xqj2B - Item table